# When appending css to head , i'm getting error. How to fix

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append this style to head

```
tbody{grid-column:1 / -1}
caption{grid-column:1 / -1}
tr{grid-column:1 / 2}
```

CSS style is not being loaded when i try to inject into the head , i'm sure something not marked up properly in my jQuery

```
jQuery('head').append('<style>#calendar tbody{grid-column:1 / -1}#calendar caption{grid-column:1 / -1}#calendar tr{grid-column:1 / 2}</style>');
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: css is not loading in head , think it has something to do with the "/" in the style when using jQuery to load

Comment: Seems to be working okay for me in testing. Could be that you're trying to append before head is initialised fully, or you have other stylesheets overriding